# Determine a relation $R$ on the set of humans on this planet by putting $(x,y) \in R$ if condition

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So i was given this question. Determine a relation $R$ on the set of humans on this planet by putting $(x,y) \in R $ if $x$ and $y$ are citizens of the same country. Is $R$ an equivalence relation?

I know the answer is no since transitivity fails but how do you test all three conditions and show that transitivity fails?

Comment: Why does transitivity fail? Are you allowing multiple citizenship?

Comment: @JohnDouma the solution only says transitivity fails

Comment: Then we are probably supposed to assume multiple citizenship because this is an equivalence relation otherwise. Assume $x$ is an american, $y$ has both american and german citizenship and $z$ is a german. Then $(x,y)\in R$ and $(y,z)\in R$ but $(x,z)$ is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transitivity fails if you allow people to be citizens of multiple countries.  We could have Alice a citizen of A, Bob a citizen of A and B, and Charlie a citizen of B.  Then Alice R Bob because of A and Bob R Charlie because of B, but we do not have Alice R Charlie.